# Hot restart error with cannot copy ipa file

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

While I am aware that Hot Restart is in preview, it was for quite a while now and my testing never really worked since the first time I've tried it. I've waited for a few VS studio versions to come up, hoping that my issue will be fixed. Since I've kept an eye on issues and haven't seen something similar, I tend to believe that the issue is locally with my setup.

Here is the situation:

- I've enabled Hot Restart in VS and added my account, picked the team (after I was added) and everything went fine without errors. I have a free apple account, but after I was added to a Team I was able to obtain automatic provisioning to work.
- I've tried to set the debug build options similar to how the simulator was set
- I've disabled device specific build as I saw in the docs that it can create problems.
- I've installed iTunes just as specified in the docs and when I connect my device to my Windows 10 PC, I can select it from the list.

So basically it looks like everything is set up. I use for testing an iphone 7 with latest iOS version.

Here is what happens:

- I've selected different types of output logs hopeing to catch some error in there that could lead me to find a solution.
- when starting to build I can see "Building offline for a local device" and I can see my provisioning file details on "Detected signed identity"
- I see no apparent error while it compiles and does its job, no complains about signing
- then it gets to the `IpaCopyToStagingDirectory` and there it starts to copy a bunch of files from bin\Iphone\Debug to Artifacts\app.iOS.dSYM where I get the final error: `Could not copy the file bin\iPhone\Debug\\app.iOS.ipa because it was not found`

If I go to the bin folder, there are many files, including `app.iOS.exe`, but indeed there is no ipa file. I also don't know why it has two \ on its path.

Any ideas why is not working?